# How to implement CHAID decision-tree using R for continuous variable

Tags: r, classification

I have 62 variables which includes both continuous variables and binary variables and 1 response variable imported from SAS.

1. How can I perform chaid using R on all the variables?
2. Can R do it on continuous variables?
3. Also there are approx 1 million rows for each variables.
   4.
   Suppose we have variables var1 to var30 as binary var31 to var61 as continuous and var62 as response. Could you illustrate with a working example? Also none of the binary variable are converted to factors using as.factor().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The original CHAID algorithm by Kass (1980) is *An Exploratory Technique for Investigating Large Quantities of Categorical Data* (quoting its original title), i.e., both dependent and explanatory variables have to be categorical (or transformed to such). This is the algorithm which is implemented in the R package `CHAID`.

Of course, there are numerous other recursive partitioning algorithms that are more or less similar to CHAID which can deal with mixed data types. For example, the CTree algorithm (conditional inference trees) is also based on significance tests and is available in `ctree()` in package `partykit`. Other popular recursive partitioning packages include `rpart` or `C50` among others. See http://CRAN.R-project.org/view=MachineLearning for an overview.

Finally, with the large number of observations, it might pay off to not only consider a single tree but an ensemble of trees, e.g., a random forest.

Comment: How can we use ensemble of trees. Suppose we have variables var1 to var30 as binary var31 to var61 as continuous and var62 as response. Could you illustrate with a working example? Also none of the binary variable are converted to factors using as.factor().

Comment: `Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘CHAID’ is not available (for R version 3.4.0)`

Comment: @ Achim Zeileis How can i install the `CHAID` package

Comment: Install it with `type ="source"` or install R 3.5.0.

Comment: Use this `install.packages("CHAID", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")` to install the CHAID package.